# TextBlock DataContext in Silverligth RIA Binding Question

Tags: silverlight, binding, service, dns, properties

I have a TextBox and i am tryingt o set the Text Property to the data coming fromt he RIA Servises ( Domain Service,

this is the code I have

```
    DiscussionAppDomainContext contextCategory = new DiscussionAppDomainContext();
    TextBlockBoardCategoryName.DataContext = contextCategory.discussion_categories;
    contextCategory.Load(contextCategory.GetDiscussion_categoryDetailsFromBoardIDQuery(this._boardID));
```

and

this is my Xaml,

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockBoardCategoryName" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=discussion_categoryDomainDataSource, Path=Data.CurrentItem.CategoryName}"/>
```

how do i set the Text property of this TextBox to the data coming from Domain Service?

is there somethign like,

```
TextBlockBoardCategoryName.Text = contextCategory.GetDiscussion_categoryDetailsFromBoardIDQuery(this._boardID)[firstRow]['ColumnName'].Text ?
```

can someone help me with this?
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should specify databinding for the Text property of the text block. You can refer to my [post](http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2011/04/silverlight-mvvm-getting-started.html) on this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Textbox binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
```

I don't know what your data looks like, but I believe your Xaml is incorrect.  You probably should think about setting the DataContext of the form/page and then allow your Textbox to inherit the datacontext from it.  That way you only set the DataContext once.

Answer (score 0):

If your DomainDataSource has been set up, you shouldn't need to write any code. The following is all that is required.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockBoardCategoryName" 
     Text={Binding CategoryName}"
     DataContext="{Binding ElementName=discussion_categoryDomainDataSource, Path=Data.CurrentItem}" />
```

Here is a breakdown of what is going on.

1. The discussion_categoryDomainDataSource.Data.CurrentItem is a database record
2. The Text={Binding CategoryName} is the CategoryName field on the record.